# Redirect URL to another domain with hiding

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, hide

When i write [www.mysite.net/abc](http://www.mysite.net/abc) it should go to the adress [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

But in the browser [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) should not be appeared, it should stay as [www.mysite.net/abc](http://www.mysite.net/abc)

With htaccess file, how can i do that?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\mywebsite\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,R=301,NE]
```

I tried that, did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You are using the flags `P` (Proxy) and `R` (Redirection) at the same time. That does not make sense. You do *not* want to redirect the request.

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\mysite\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?abc(?:/(.*))$ https://www.example.com/$1 [P]
```

An alternate implementation, which does *not* require the rewriting module would be:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /abc https://www.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /abc https://www.example.com/
```

You certainly can implement such rules in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but I would strongly recommend to use the central configuration of the http host instead.

Comment: I still could not do it.
My whole .htaccess file is look like:


    Redirect 302 /abc https://example.com
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\mysite\.net$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^/?abc(?:/(.*))$ https://example.com [P]

When i delete the redirect 302 code, direction is not working

Comment: With this .htaccess file, redirection to example.com is working however still in my browser www.example.com is shown, i do not want that, example.com should be hidden under the mysite.net/abc. How can i do it? @arkascha

Comment: Take a look at your configuration file. Right as the first rule you implement a redirection: ` Redirect 302 /abc example.com`. That is what is done. Your browser is redirected. Regardless of what you implement afterwards, that is irrelevant. I already explained that the combination of redirection and proxy does not make any sense. How should that work? Remove that redirection if you want to implement a proxy. It is either or, not both.

Comment: If the proxy does not work, then you have to dig deeper. First you need to make sure that the proxy module is actually loaded into your http server? Did you take care of that at all? How? Second you need to check your http server's error log file when you make a request: does it contain any errors? If so, which?